# How to open react app in Android Studio's emulator?

Tags: android, react-native

```
$ npx react-native run-android

info JS server already running.
info Launching emulator...
info Successfully launched emulator.
info Installing the app...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.lastIndexOf(String)" because "path" is null
        at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistName(PathAssembler.java:83)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistribution(PathAssembler.java:39)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:58)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:63)

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.lastIndexOf(String)" because "path" is null
        at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistName(PathAssembler.java:83)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistribution(PathAssembler.java:39)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:58)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:63)

    at makeError (E:\Code Projects\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at E:\Code Projects\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (E:\Code Projects\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (E:\Code Projects\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:142:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

I have followed all the instructions in react docs but somehow i can't open the app in emulater.
after running `npx react-native run-android` it open emulater but can't dispaly the app in the emulater. I have strictly follow the doc and done every step mantioned there.

Comment: check your java version please and let me know

Comment: PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> java -version

openjdk version "11.0.17" 2022-10-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-11.0.17+8 (build 11.0.17+8)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-11.0.17+8 (build 11.0.17+8, mixed mode)

Comment: can you set all the environment  variables see here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F7xdbsjFGtU&t=1577s

Comment: something wrong in setup

Comment: can you please tell me which setup I mess up. I have set all the env variables correctly.

Comment: I think one that is causing the problem is Gradle but I'm not able to understand it properly.

Comment: what is your Gradle version

Comment: its Gradle 7.5.1
Kotlin:       1.6.21
Groovy:       3.0.10
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          19.0.1 (Oracle Corporation 19.0.1+10-21)
OS:           Windows 11 10.0 amd64

Comment: npm :6.14.15,node:v14.18.1 gradle:7.3.3 or 7.5 jdk:11.0.16I have use my friend also same issue she change all version like my version  or my friend issue is soul

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250806/discussion-between-gattu-patel-and-chaman-narved).